# How do I implement binary search using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sorting, binary-search

I know the basic concepts of binary search and binary insertion sort, but how can I use that knowledge with MySQL? How do I query to find a username in 1000 alphabetized rows and how do I query to insert a username?

Comment: MySQL does this for you. There's no reason to manually find or insert something with a binary search or binary insertion sort. The very concept makes no sense in a relational database.

Comment: Basically when you search by primary key, MyQSL performs a binary search

Comment: @tadman Oh so when finding a particular username in a list of 1000 unalphabetized rows, it uses binary search?

Comment: @VitaliiStrimbanu Even if that primary key is the username field?

Comment: @user2896120 no, for username field you need to create an index, [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: @VitaliiStrimbanu Hmm that link is broken

Comment: Maybe it does, maybe it doesn't. It's not really relevant, the database implementation isn't meant to be exposed. You can read up on [how MySQL uses indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html) if you want more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't. You index the column and let the database use whatever algorithm it chooses for the index. This will probably be a B+-tree, which is much more efficient than a binary search when the data is on a disk.

Comment: Oh so I just insert whatever data into my table and whichever I want to retrieve it uses the most efficient algorithm to retrieve the data set?

Comment: Yes, that's what a databae is for.

Comment: Thanks! Keep it up!